# Seeking data that shows stay at home orders by United States county for COVID-19 crisis

Tags: geospatial, usa, covid19

I'm looking for GIS data that shows which US counties are issuing "Stay at Home" orders all across the US. It would also be helpful if the data included which types of businesses were allowed to be open, and what restrictions are in place (if any). I have found data broken down by state. I cannot find county data.

Does anyone know where I can find this information?

This is for a COVID-19 mapping web application. I need to access the data programmatically, so any data in JSON or csv format would be great.

Comment: Have you looked ESRI Open Data ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately they don't have up to date county data. I found one data source that was public health emergencies by county, and it hasn't been updated in a month.